# Looking for TFS 2015 Update 2 RC2

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm attempting to restore the application tier of our TFS server and fear that I'm up a creek without a paddle. When verifying the configuration, I get the following error.

> The selected database is incompatible with this application tier. The
>   database has the following schema version: "Microsoft Team Foundation
>   Server 2015 Update 2 RC2". This application tier can be used only with
>   a configuration database with the following schema version: "Microsoft
>   Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2".

It appears that I've installed update 2 on my app tier, but the databases are using update 2 rc2.  Since it was a release candidate, it is no longer available from MS and has been replaced by the official update 2.

Help!  Does anyone know where I can find TFS 2015 Update 2 RC2?  Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can upgrade in place.  I was able to install TFS 2015 UPDATE 3 on my application server and then select the "upgrade" option during configuration.